# Portal : Do I really need a Portal

Tags: web, portal

Do I really need a Portal  ??

Always one question comes to my mind , why do people go for Portal development , can't they manage with a normal web aplication , managing the UI Page  with different sections? I am sorry if my question is not valid.

Or In what scenarios do we actually need a web Portal?

Comment: What kind of portal do you are talking about? J2EE portal, php CMS portal, other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing a UI page with different sections is fine if your users are using only your application.  However, a portal allows your users to use multiple applications (and many of them not created by you) and kind of 'aggregate' their content on one page; well at least have a place which provides easy access to them on one page.  The emphasis here is on multiple applications; these are applications that you as a developer may have no control over; they may have been written by a third party (such as Google, or any other developer).

The items on a portal page may not necessarily be from the problem domain that you are developing for.  There's no reason why a user can't put the local weather on the same page that he's examining the inventory for his company.

Portals provide a single point of entry; that's the key point.  A portal also provides some other niceties such as managed logins.  If you are creating an application for a customer, and you don't have a need for a portal, a portal may be overkill (and probably is, if you have to ask).

Comment: That was good explanation , thank you , one more question , can https://www.meebo.com/messenger can be treated as a portal ??

Comment: If you mean 'Is it a portal?', the short answer is no.  An example of a portal is iGoogle.  One thing that gives it away is little boxes that you can add to your screen.  In the purest sense, a portal should offer more than iGoogle offers (from what I know about iGoogle).  The reason is that other companies should be able to create applications that can be used in the portal.  I'm not sure if iGoogle has the ability where other people can create applications for it; maybe it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me understand what a portal really means.